# Character encoding in LibreOffice Calc of an existing XLW file

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice-calc

I have an **existing** .XLW file (created in the early 1990's with Microsoft Excel).  LibreOffice Calc (7.2.7.2) opens it and displays it very nicely.

However, since it contains characters in a non-English language, it displays them in incorrect and unintelligible character encoding.

Is there a way to make Calc display them in 8-bit encoding such as ISO/IEC 8859-8 ?

Note: I am not asking about [saving](https://superuser.com/questions/1102217/how-to-change-libreoffice-default-text-encoding) but rather about [reading](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-do-you-change-the-encoding-for-certain-file-types/52833).

Comment: Do you know the original encoding and font? Maybe you only need to install the font and it will work. If you can't get the font and it is in a legacy encoding of some sort (not Unicode) then you would need to use an encoding converter such as my Calc extension at https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/lingtools. If you need to create your own mapping then it requires a lot of work though, determining the corresponding input and output values for each character in the language.

Comment: @JimK Interestingly, I still have an old VMWare VM lying around Running Windows 2000 with an Microsoft Excel 2002 SP2. It opened the file with proper display of aforementioned character encoding. I copied it and then did "Paste Special" which invoked a dialog box with encodings to choose from. I selected UTF-8 and lo-and-behold it pasted it properly to LibreOffice. I then saved it as .ODS. I guess this is a nice workaround.